# LDAP Logon History

Tags: php, activerecord, ldap, windows-server-2008

Is it possible to know the login history of a user through LDAP? I'm trying to find a way bit so far I can only get the lastLogon and lastLogout.

Regards,
Elkas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on LDAP backend.
You put windows-server-2008 tag, so I expect you mean MS Active Directory or AD-LDS instance (aka ADAM).
If so, you can query security event log on LDAP server (DC), if security auditing is on (as of default is on).
You will need pretty high privilege to do this,so first ask domain admins to grant this permission.
You can forgot for PHP or maybe you find some pecl package to read windows event log records.

If you will able to read security event log, you need to filter out lot of data like logon type (you will be interested in network-logon).
However, depends on load of domain controller and number of active user accounts in AD, it will take lot of time to do this.

Comment: Exactly. I put the Windows Server 2008 tag because the AD its on a WS2k8. Thanks for the info mate.