# Getting the next-to-last logon via LDAP(or something else) in a windows domain

Tags: c#, windows, ldap

I wrote a program that informs the user that he needs to change his password in a few days. The Program is executed every time the user logs on via logon script. Because of the infrastructure of our systems(citrix terminal server) it is likely that several log ons are executed on one log on(I hope that makes sense). 
 Because of that thet notification for changing the password might appear several times. Since the program is executed on logon the LDAP Property "lastlogon" is useless to me. Is there a way to check the next-to-last logon date? At the moment i realised this by checking the last modified date of a file that gets created by the program. But that solution isn't that great.

```
        string UserName =  System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; //Get username oft the current User
        int charindex = UserName.IndexOf(@"\"); //Index of the first "\" in the username to distinguish Domain name from Username
        UserName = UserName.Remove(0, charindex + 1); //Remove Domain name fro username

        SearchResult sr;
        using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher()) //search logged in user
        {                
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("pwdLastSet"); //Date when the Password was chnaged  (as FileTime format - 64 bit Int)
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastLogon"); //useles
            ds.PageSize = 1;
            ds.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", UserName); 
            sr = ds.FindOne(); // Find User in AD
        }
        long pwChangedDate =(long)sr.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0];  
        long DateNow = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime(); // Write current date in variable as FileTime format
        long pwChangedDays = (DateNow - pwChangedDate) / (86400000000000 / 100); //Calculate days since passwort was cahnged   86400000000000 / 100 = One day in the FileTime format            
        notificationDays = pwValidity - notificationDays;           

        DateTime fileLastWrite = File.GetLastWriteTime(filepath);

        if (pwChangedDays >= notificationDays && pwChangedDays <= pwValidity && fileLastWrite < DateTime.Today)
        {
            File.Create(filepath);
            string remainingDays = Convert.ToString(pwValidity - pwChangedDays); //Days till Password needs to be changed 
            MessageBox.Show(remainingDays)
        }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you've defined `sr`. Is the logon script setup to run in the context of the interactive user? Does Citrix launch additional interactive sessions with it's added logons?

Comment: Did you check for other candidate fields within the AD (e.g. `lastLogon` or `lastLogonTimestamp`)?. Maybe simply browse the AD by using something like [Sysinternals ADExplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/adexplorer.aspx) and check if you find any timestamp fields that could help you.

Comment: I added the code of how i devined the sr.

Comment: Sorry... I made a mistake there,, "lastlogon" is the candidate field that is useless to me, since the program is executed rigt after the logon. pwLastSet is absolutely useful to me. And yes.. I did some research on that topic.. but culdn't find any useful information.

Comment: if it's not there, you may need to turn it on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410983/ldap-logon-history . After reading that, my guess is your filepath hack is suddenly looking really great.

Comment: Exactly.. Suddely i love my File Hack ^^ Thanks for that hint, but i wont be allowed to pull that off.. Would be great if there's and easier solution for it.. But after a lot of research it doesn't seem to be the case.